# switching to R version 3.1 from 3.0

Tags: r

I have downloaded R version 3.1 and when I enter R.home()  it returns the folder for 3.0

> R.home()
>   [1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1"

but  I wish to switch it to be 3.1.

The reason is that I am in need of using devtools, which requires me to have 3.1

> install.packages("devtools")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/software/Rpackages’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)

Comment: look at the `installr` package

Comment: I found [this](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) helpful in explaining the use of `installr` package as @jdharrison suggested

Comment: I get an error when running installr.   something along the "there was an error installing the file..."  I had removed all created files regarding R version 3.1.0 and am now re installing.... advice?

Comment: Warning message:
In install.R() :
  There was some problem with installing R.  Some files are not what they should be (e.g: check MD5 sums did not pass all the tests). 
  You can try installing R again (either manually or through install.R()), 
  and if the problem persists you can file a bug report by running:  bug.report(package = 'installr')

Comment: so because I have issues with installr package, how do I manually upgrade to r version 3.1.0.  I can download R version 3.1.0 manually from the Cran site... but my interface R studio, after i download it locally to my computer, still is pointing to the old version of r when I type R.home().   ?  thank you very much

Comment: You can change the version of R that you are using (if downloaded, in windows, with Rstudio) by clicking `tools > global options > r version` then restart rstudio